# How to Identify a Required attribute from WSDL file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I am creating a WCF service here is the DataContract section of the service i am setting the `Fromdate` field a required attribute.

```
[DataContract(Name = "PriceCalculationRequest")]
    public class PriceReq
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "PickupDate", Order = 1, IsRequired = true , EmitDefaultValue=true)]
        private DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ReturnDate", Order = 3)]
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string PickupLocation { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public string ReturnLocation { get; set; }

        public string CarType { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the `wsdl` file generated from the above code, how can i identify which attribute is a required attribute,

```
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="pickupDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="returnDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="pickupLocation" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="vehiclePreference" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with like that unfortunately :( You would need to use `minOccurs`, but I can't remember how you can implement that in WCF, but it is possible.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the significance of minOccurs="0".

Comment: It should become `minOccurs=1` and `maxOccurs=1`, I'll see what I can dig up for you.

Comment: Perhaps the bottom answer of the following thread could be useful to you: http://forums.asp.net/t/1714450.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you rebuild your service project after you make the modifications. This is what I'm getting:

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="PickupDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PickupLocation" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReturnDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReturnLocation" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set IsRequired=true it shows minoccurs="0"  saying it is required

```
minOccurs="0"
```

Refer this link for explanation: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints

Comment: Chirag it's not like that minOccurs="0" determines, minimum number of times the element can occur.The value can be 0 or 1.(Refer http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_all.asp) Default value is 1. if the element is required, minOccurs="0" will not be displayed as suggested by alex Pickupdate is required attribute here.